# How to get row count using primeng turbotable with help of primeng

Tags: angular6, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have tried to display current table row count with total count i got total value count via #table.value.length but i can't able to get current page row count, I used turbotable in primeng. I need to display like blow image for total count/ row count i.e Tatal: 10/5.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using pagination for the table. You can use rows and totalRecords state of pagination to display total count/ row count

```
<p-table #tabel ...></p-table>

{{table.totalRecords}}/{{table.rows}}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but before your answer i found solution. Thanks for spending

Comment: I had a another problem while i click next page if that page has 1 record means the count need to display totalrecords / 1 , but instead of display rows value 5

Comment: @SaranViji If you have a new question, post a new question. Don’t comment. And _don’t_ post it on Meta Stack Overflow.